# Using SSJS or EL to call a Bean

Tags: xpages, el, xpages-ssjs

I have a managed-bean that needs a parameter passed during the call.

if the parameter is hard coded into the call I can use either SSJS or El to make my call so the SSJS call would be WFSAppProperties().get("Demo").getFilePath(); and I can getFilePath using EL. However, I need to replace "Demo" with sessionScope.get("ssApplication"), which of course can not be passed to EL. I see some work-arounds with EL but they all look fairly complex. So the question is -- I understand that EL is faster the SSJS call, but is the performance hit significant enough to warrant some of the work-around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SessionScope is available in EL as well. Did you try:

```
             WFSAppProperties[sessionScope["ssApplication"]]
```

should work.

Comment: I never tried that just read that you can't pass parameters to EL and took it at face value. Thanks

Comment: The statement is correct for simple value bindings. The very moment your bean implements the Map interface, you provide the key and EL does a Map.get(key). What you do inside your get(...) method is up to you.